# Translation doesn't work Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to translate my platform. First I made a simple layout for trying the trans fuction. When I make sure about it, I will make it for the real case. you can see the controller, index.html.twig, config.yml, messages.es and messages.en:

```
....

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\Translator;

class DummyController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/prova",name="role_public_dummy")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        //$locale = $request->getLocale();
        $request=$this->getRequest();
        $locale = $request->getPreferredLanguage();//catching browser language
        $request->setLocale($locale);
        $this->get('session')->set('_locale', $locale);

        return array();

    }

}
```

index.html.twig

```
{% trans %}index.1{% endtrans %}
```

config.yml

```
framework:
    #esi:             ~
    translator:      { fallback: "%locale%" }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
        handler_id:  ~
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true
```

messages.es

```
index.1: "CASA"
```

messages.en

```
index.1: "HOME"
```

So, I don't understand why symfony uses always the locale 'en' when it uses the 'trans' function. It's like it doesn't catch the locale of the session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to set locale to `Request` object, but in controller it takes no effect on `Translator` service so as it has been already configured earlier.
I guess you should try setting locale for your `Translator` service directly or creating separate action where you will be only setting locale to session and redirecting to other action.

Comment: ok, but so, how would code be? I mean, how can I set the locale in the trans service? Ive been reading symfony doc, and I didn't find the way.

Comment: Check out http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Translation/Translator.html setLocale method